# Magento2 Show products from a specific category on homepage

Tags: magento2, category-products

I am trying to load a custom phtml on my homepage that would show products from a specific category within an owl carousel. My issue is I am notable to get the product listing to work.

Code here

> app/code/Firstimage/ProductSlider/Block/productslider.php

```
 namespace Firstimage\ProductSlider\Block;
 class ProductSlider extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {    
     protected $_categoryFactory;

     public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        array $data = []
     ) {    
       $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
       parent::__construct($context, $data);
   }

   public function getCategory($categoryId) 
   {
       $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
       $category->load($categoryId);
       return $category;
       return $category->getData();
   }

   public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId) 
   {
     $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
     $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
     return $products;
     return $products->getData();
   }
}
```

Then my frontend phtml files which is located

> app/design/frontend/firstimagedesign/rjtheme/Magento_Theme/templates/html/favoritestyles.phtml

```
<?php
$categoryId = 81; // this is the category holding your products  
$categoryProducts = $block->getCategoryProducts($categoryId);
foreach ($categoryProducts as $product) 
{
    //print_r($product->getData());
    // printing category name and url
    echo $product->getName() . ' - ' . $product->getProductUrl() . '<br />';
}
```

My issue seems to be now that in my phtml file the `$categoryProducts` has a value of NULL and not sure why since category ID 81 has products and is enabled.

Comment: hello you are the magento 1 code Mage but not support magento 2 Mage.you are this line mage $products = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category')->load($categoryId) check please > https://prnt.sc/s0pj5b

Comment: How would I change that?

Comment: i think this type :--- $products = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);

Comment: I changed my approach using http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-all-products-of-a-category/

Comment: products are showing or not in category is 81??

Comment: If I go to the category page the products show but now my homepage says error has occured while generating this content and when I look at the exception.log I see an error that says Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()  for the favoritestyles.phtml file

Comment: productslider.php in file you change first function return $category->getData(); and second function change  return $products->getData();

Comment: @ Mohit can you show me how that file should be edited?

Comment: two function last line add this code return $category->getData(); and return $products->getData();

Comment: Look at my OP I edited the productslider.php last two lines in the last function. let me know if that is correct.

Comment: no, this function `public function getCategory($categoryId)` add last line this  `return $category->getData();` and this function `public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId)` add last line this `return $products->getData();`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106802/discussion-between-jayreis-and-mohit-patel).

Comment: I updated my OP with the updated productslider.php
however I then rand compile deploy and i still get a error that says We're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this content.

Answer (score 0):

I've checked your block class `ProductSlider` code and found an issue with the injected class `\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context`.

This class is used for the admin block class. You should use `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context` for frontend block class to make it work.

I've corrected your ProductSlider class code and add it below.

```
<?php

namespace Firstimage\ProductSlider\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class ProductSlider extends Template
{
    /**
     * @var CategoryFactory
     */
    protected $_categoryFactory;

    /**
     * CategoryProducts constructor.
     * @param Template\Context $context
     * @param CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        CategoryFactory $categoryFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_categoryFactory = $categoryFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @param $categoryId
     * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category
     */
    public function getCategory($categoryId)
    {
        $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create();
        $category->load($categoryId);
        return $category;
    }

    /**
     * @param $categoryId
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId)
    {
        $products = $this->getCategory($categoryId)->getProductCollection();
        $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        return $products;
    }
}
```

Please cross-check the name of the block class file, it should be `ProductSlider.php` not `productslider.php`.

Also, add the template file under the module instead in the theme on the below path (optional step).

```
Firstimage/ProductSlider/view/frontend/templates/favoritestyles.phtml
```

Call your block class with the below code on the home page.

```
{{block class="Firstimage\ProductSlider\Block\ProductSlider" template="Firstimage_ProductSlider::favoritestyles.phtml"}}
```

**Hope it helps!!!**